# Limits of Integration in Trig Substitution

Tags: calculus

Lets say you must perform a simple integral with trigonometric substitution - we'll choose $\int{\sqrt{1-x^2}dx}$ from $0$ to $17$.  Now we use $x = \sin(t)$ for our substitution.  Here's my problem: the limits of integration for $x$ range from $0$ to $17$, but $\sin$ never achieves a value greater than $1$.  How do we change the limits of integration to accommodate this?

Note: I am not interested in writing in the limits at the very end, after back-substituting.

Comment: If you are dealing with real calculus  $1-x^2\ge0\implies -1\le x\le1$

Comment: You should not be trying to integrate the function from $0$ to $17$, it is not defined beyond $1$.

Comment: "How do we change the limits of integration to accommodate this?" Simple answer: you don't.

Comment: @AndréNicolas well it's just not defined in the real domain

Comment: @WolterHellmund: The OP is likely doing a first calculus course. Complex integration can wait.

Comment: Sure, well just wanted to let that sink into him

Answer (score 3):

The function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not defined for $x\gt 1$, so you will not be wanting to integrate it from $0$ to $17$. Thus the issue does not arise.

As $t$ travels from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, $\sin t$ travels smoothly from $-1$ to $1$, so the substitution is suitable for $\int_a ^b\sqrt{1-t^2}\,dt$, where $-1\le a\le b\le 1$.

Once *can* imagine running into problems, with for example $\int_0^3\sqrt{17-x^2}\,dx$. This is perfectly well defined. The substitution $x=\sin t$ would not be suitable, since $\sin t$ does not take on values in the interval $(2,3]$. Luckily, the substitution is not useful! For this problem we would use $x=\sqrt{17}\sin t$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are substituting $x=\sin t$, then the resultant integral should be $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos^2 t dt}}$